# Correct flag overridden by user of higher reputation

Tags: discussion

So as you can see my reputation being only 29, I have to wait for user with higher reputation to approve my flagging. Although I flagged a question correctly, it was disapproved and now the number of flags that  I can raise is reduced to 9 from 10, I guess. And the 'duplicate' link this user provided is incorrect. But then I cannot connect to him with this issue.

How do I connect to that user and raise my concern, if he is unavailable in chat?

This is the flagged question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40085578/fetach-all-rows- with the "approved " duplicate-to being: [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql)

Comment: You only have 9 flags left for this day. You have 10 flags every day. Also as I understand you you flagged a question for duplicate an another user suggested another one?!

Comment: What is the reason for down vote here?

Comment: It's called "someone having a different opinion than you".

Comment: @Rizier123 yes, another user with 'higher reputation' suggested another question as its original, which by the way, is not related to the actual flagged question.

Comment: Here on Meta, downvotes are also used to express disagreement, so whoever downvoted probably disagrees with you. In general, questions that suggest someone is "bullying" don't do well here. I think you should [edit] the question, and give it a more neutral tone. "Why was my flag rejected", and explain why the duplicate in question is not correct.

Comment: What was the flag about?

Comment: @b.g So what is the problem if someone else suggested another duplicate?

Comment: @Rizier123 the problem is the other suggested question has no connection to the asked question!

Comment: Mind linking the questions? A bit of context would be helpful here.... Because what you describe seems to be exactly how the system is intended to work, if that high rep user has a gold badge in tags on the question

Comment: @b.g If the question doesn't get closed with the wrong duplicate it is not a problem. And if you have 50 reputation you can comment on it and explain why you think the duplicate is wrong, but for now you did the right thing and flagged the question with the duplicate you think is correct.

Comment: @b.g Again, downvotes indicate disagreement, and they cost you absolutely nothing on meta. Don't take it so personally.

Comment: @meagar I didn't take anything personally, I am just finding it funny, the way people react. Since, this question can't be asked in the , I don't know what to call it, 'technical community'?, I came here hoping, maybe there's something that can be done, but in vain!

Comment: @b.g Something can be done... and is being done. You've had a rough start here on MSO, but you are not alone in that. For what it's worth, the eyes of the community are now on the question, and the closure will be considered by some of the people here. Whether that will result in reopening the question.. time will tell.

Answer (score 9):

You don't have to connect to this specific user. If a question is closed as a duplicate, and you believe this is wrong, there are a few things you can do.

You can raise the issue on Meta, as you have done right now. Meta can be a hard place; be sure to phrase the question as neutral as you can. Link to the question, and explain why you believe it is not a duplicate.
A humble attitude works best here; be willing to accept that you may be wrong.

"X was wrongfully closed as a duplicate of Y" asserts that someone else is wrong, and as such, is confrontational.
By contrast, "I'd like to understand why X was closed as a duplicate of Y, despite ..." is neutral. That is generally received better here.

Once you have 50 points or more, you can comment on the question.

Once you have 3000 points or more, you can cast a reopen vote. It's generally a good idea to add a comment *why* the question should be reopened. 3000 points may sound like a lot right now, but if you manage to provide quality content, you will have it one day.

You *could* also edit the question, which makes it eligible for reopening. However, editing it just to get it reopened is abuse of the system, and not recommended.